# Working out area of certain class types within polygon using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analysis

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I am trying to use a DEM to determine land management units based on combinations of slope and aspect.

As per the task I have created three individual boolean 'Class' rasters which have specific aspect/slope details. I also have a shapefile of land regions - which has area Ha data contained per region.

I want to work out the area of each "Class" within each region. I know this shouldn't be that difficult but I can't work out which tool I should be using.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the tool called "[tabulate area](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/tabulate-area.htm)" for that. It requires a Spatial Analyst licence. To avoid rounding issue, specify a pixel size equivalent to your raster resolution in the analysis setting